# Nginx, set cache to expire based on time of day and every 2 hours

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm looking to set up the cash on Nginx so the cache for certain files will never last more than 2 hours, but also to have the cache expire at 6:15 am every day. The issue I'm having is setting both of these time constraints in the same location block.

so far I have this

```
uwsgi_cache_path /data/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g;
.
.
.
location ~* /my/path/and/image.*\.png$ {
    expires 7200;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/my_project_name.sock;
    uwsgi_cache_key $request_uri;
    uwsgi_cache my_cache;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

I've looked at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html 
 which set the cache to expire using `expires @15h30m;` so I tried setting

```
expires 7200, @6h15m;
```

but that syntax does not seem to be accepted.

note: in addition, I also need to have the user's browsers cache expiring every 30 min or so.

Comment: I don't think you can do a time of day thing. If you really need that you could have a cron job delete the files in the cache folder and restart Nginx, but that gives you downtime. You control browser caching using headers, but you're using old headers like Pragma. Suggest you should read a tutorial on this. I have a [brief tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/#ccheaders) available but you probably want something more comprehensive.

Comment: @Tim.  The link I provided from nginx indicates that time of day is possible.
"The time in the Expires field is computed as a sum of the current time [...] In addition, it is possible to specify a time of day using the “@” prefix" and then it gives `expires @15h30m;` as an example.

Comment: You should be able to use `Lua` for this. https://scene-si.org/2017/01/08/improving-nginx-lua-cache-purges/ and https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/nginx/nginx-time-based-rewriting-rules/ should give you enough information to get you started

Comment: Interesting, you can expire at a given time. Looks like you can choose one or the other, time or duration. I think it simply sets a header for the cache / browsers to check against. I suggest again that you should read a comprehensive tutorial on browser caching headers - I found one a year or so ago when I wrote my tutorial, but I didn't keep a link.